# Findall to identify a specific title in a downloaded HTML page

Tags: python, html, findall

I have to download the source code of an HTML page and then have to find specific titles and print them on the GUI in Python. I am able to download the HTML file but unable to find my elements of interest in the downloaded HTML page. As an example, I am using this webpage currently.

https://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/release-date/coming-soon/all/date

The first game to be released is "Lovecraft's Untold Stories". I want this title and print in my GUI. In the HTML page, this title is printed through the

tag. I am using the Findall method but it returns nothing.
P.S. I cannot use any other library including Beautiful Soap or requests. I am restricted to use only urllib, findall, finditer, MULTILINE, DOTALL. The currently implemented piece of code is shown below.

```
def game_function():
   game = Tk()
   game.geometry('600x400')
   game.title('Upcoming Video Game Releases')
   game.resizable(0,0)
   opener = urllib.request.FancyURLopener({})
   url = "file:///D:/Riz/Poppie%202/Upcoming%20Video%20Game%20Releases%20for%202019%20-%20Metacritic.html"

  with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
     encoding = response.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')
     html = response.read().decode(encoding)
  print("",html)
  title_tag = '<h3>(.*)</h3>'
  title_1 = findall(title_tag, html)
  print("",title_1)

  title1_subtitle = Label(game, text = title_1, bg='white', fg='black', font = ('Arial', 14, 'bold'))
  title1_subtitle.place(relx=0.8, rely=0.49)
  title1_subtitle.configure(wraplength='260')

  game.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is caused by fact that there are newlines (`\n`) inside `h3` tags. In `re.findall`'s first argument `.` means *any character except newline* unless you use `re.DOTALL` as third argument. Moreover you should use non-greedy version.
I hope following example would make it clear:

```
import re
txt = '''<h3>
SomeTitle
</h3>
AnotherContent
<h3>
AnotherTitle
</h3>'''
nodotall = re.findall('<h3>(.*)</h3>',txt)
withdotall = re.findall('<h3>(.*)</h3>',txt,re.DOTALL)
nongreedy = re.findall('<h3>(.*?)</h3>',txt,re.DOTALL)
print(nodotall) # [] i.e. nothing found
print(withdotall) # ['\nSomeTitle\n</h3>\nAnotherContent\n<h3>\nAnotherTitle\n'] i.e. everything between first <h3> and last </h3>
print(nongreedy) # ['\nSomeTitle\n', '\nAnotherTitle\n'] i.e. desired output
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks
Just another small question; as I am printing the message in the Python GUI's, how can I print numerical number with the title obtained? For instance,
1. First title
2. First title

Comment: @JoeJulen: for printing items from list with numbers take look at enumerate: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/